# Compare one nested dictionary to list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to remove a nested dictionary from a dictionary of a lists of nested dictionaries, based on whether or not it occurs in that dictionary, and return the filtered dictionary.

So,

```
large_dict = {

k1 : [{id: 123, name: 'foo', type: 'thing', places: ['hobbiton', 'narnia']}, 
{id: 456, name: 'bar', type: 'gizmo', places: NaN}, 
{id: 789, name: 'python', type: 'thingamajig', places: NaN}],

k2: [{id: 101, name: 'app', type: 'bauble'}]

}

valid_dict = {

k1: {id: 123, name: 'foo', type: 'thing', places: ['hobbiton', 'narnia']}, 
k2: {id: 101, name: 'app', type: 'bauble', places: NaN}

}
```

The desired output is to return `large_dict` but without `valid_dict`, so desired output would be to return all the dictionaries that don't occur in `valid_dict`, another hurdle is that some values only appear in the large dict once so I don't want to get rid of them:

```
filtered_dict = {

    k1 : [{id: 456, name: 'bar', type: 'gizmo', places: NaN}, 
    {id: 789, name: 'python', type: 'thingamajig', places: NaN}],

    k2: {id: 101, name: 'app', type: 'bauble', places: NaN}

    }
```

I've currently tried doing a reverse intersection, but I can't quite qet it. And this bit of code, but I keep getting

```
un_rel_dict[a] = [{t['id']: t['attributes.name']}, {'type':t['type']}]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

unmatched_dict = {}
for (k, v), (i, j) in zip(best_match.items(), match_dict.items()):
    unmatched_dict[k] = [x for x in v if not x in j]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please add string on your example code so that one can use your input as example

Comment: Your dicts are not proper dicts. `places =  ...` is a syntax error.

Comment: @lostin fixed, sorry long day!